# How to switch audio output?

Tags: bluetooth-audio, nexus-6p, 7.1-nougat

I have several devices that can connect to my phone via bluetooth. For example, bluetooth headphones, my car etc.

What happens is that if one of these devices is on and in proximity, I actually have to turn off the bluetooth in order to play Spotify though my phone speakers.

Is it possible to switch audio outputs when they are multiple devices connected that can play audio? The only thing I've found is the phone app which allows you to do it, but I would like something device wide and supporting all apps.

I have a Nexus 6p with Nougat 7.1 installed.

Comment: In Settings - Bluetooth, can you see individual devices? If yes, click the device and it will tell you if it's using the device for audio (indicated by ticks). Cancelling the ticks should un-route the audio, but I haven't done this myself so I can't be sure - let me know if this actually works.